# Unlock session with connected monitor when the laptop lid is closed

Tags: display, laptop, monitoring

Recently I got a ThinkPad T460S with Dell UltraSharp U2715H for working. 
I tried to work with the lid of the laptop closed and working with the monitor as the primary screen, it work great but when I try to "lock" the session the computer looks like it get "suspended" and I am only available to "wake up" when I open the lid. After the screen "wake up" only appears the signal in the laptop, no evidence on the "main" monitor until I unlock the computer.

P.D.: I am using a "ThinkPad 90W Ultra Dock" (dock station) and I am not sure if it has something to do...

P.D.2.: I want archive to unlock the computer from my monitor without opening the lid.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditto with a regular external monitor over TB (no dock)

USB keyboard doesn't wake the laptop.. the lid has to be opened :(